# Is it possible to connect to non-miso device

Tags: connector, spi, serial

Is it possible to setup a connection to my device? Is it SPI ?

The device is x96 android tv box, (manufacturer unknown, may be TT TV Box, listed as both x96 and X96, its casing is lower case). Managed to brick it. On others I’ve used another technique for connecting which o has an available here. For more info it’s a s905x soc board with on board storage and wifi.

What pins need linking? I usually use RX/TX/GND but there isn’t any pins for it on this device.

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thank you. [image: ch341a]

[image: s905x board]

Comment: With pins labelled just "DAT" and "CLK" my first thought is it probably uses I²C or I²S but it could be any number of protocols, including something bespoke designed for this device's specific application. We can't tell you more without knowing what the device is and what it's meant to do.

Comment: Just concerned to randomly connect pins as I burnt out my other uart board yesterday. Got very hot.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your post would be a lot less confusing if brand names and part numbers were capitalised properly in both the title and post. It *does* matter. You can [edit] any time to improve your posts.

Comment: I'd guess that STB = CS, CLK = CLK, DAT = MISO and/or MOSI

Comment: So you have a bricked TV box with limited info and a Chinese EEPROM programmer with info in Chinese (but apparently a community) and you are trying to get them to communicate.   I'd rather take the odds of winning the lottery!